# How to organize concurrent request processing in Scala?

Tags: scala, concurrency, client-server, actor

Suppose I have a server in `Scala`, which processes incoming client requests. I have a function `def process(req: Request): Response` to process requests. Now I would like to process only `K` requests concurrently and keep `M` requests in queue.

In `Java` I would probably create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `K` threads and a queue of size `M`. Now I wonder how to do that in `Scala` with `Actors/Futures` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must have `def process(req: Request): Response)`, then I think your Scala solution may turn out to be similar to Java. If you can have `def process(req: Request): Future[Response]`, the it opens other possibilities.

When using futures, you provide (implicitly or explicitly) an [execution context](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%24) that can be constructed from a Java executor. So you would be able to choose your thread pool size and queue size that way. The benefit of using futures is that you can compose them with `map` and `flatMap` and a few other combinators. See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html for more information.

With actors, you have another model of concurrency where you can create `K` actors. You can have a [router](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/scala/routing.html) that dispatches each request to the actors. Each actor is independently processes the request and sends the `Response` to whatever needs it when processing is complete. The nice part about actors is that each actor being independent does not typically share anything with other actors, so you don't have to synchronize the code. See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/general/terminology.html for more information.

Overall I think Scala can use anything that Java has, and provides more mechanisms to do more complex things.